# AWS StepFunctions - Merge and flatten the task output combined with the original input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

How do we use `Parameters`, `ResultPath` and `ResultSelector` to combine the results of a `Task` with the original input in the same JSON level?

I checked the [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html) on AWS, but it seems that `ResultSelector` always create a new dictionary which puts it in 1-level below on the result.

Example input

```json
    {
        "status": "PENDING",
        "uuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "john.doe@email.com",
        "orders": [
            {
                "item_uuid": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
                "quantities": 2,
                "price": 2.38,
                "created_at": 16049331038000
            }
        ]
    
    
    }
```

State Machine definition

```json
    "Review": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:activity:Review",
      "ResultPath": null,
      "Next": "Processing",
      "Parameters": {
        "task_name": "REVIEW_REQUIRED",
        "uuid.$": "$.uuid"
      }
    },
```

Example output from `Review` Activity

```json
    {
        "review_status": "APPROVED"
    }
```

**Question**
How do I update the State Machine definition to  combined the result of `Review` Activity and the original input to something as below?

```json
   {
        "status": "PENDING",
        "uuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "john.doe@email.com",
        "orders": [
            {
                "item_uuid": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
                "quantities": 2,
                "price": 2.38,
                "created_at": 16049331038000
            }
        ],
        "review_status": "APPROVED"
    }
```

*NOTE*
I don't have access to the Activity code, just the definition file.

Answer (score 6):

While Step Function does not allow you to do so, you can create a Pass state that flattens the input as a workaround.

Example Input:

```js
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "lambdaResult": {
    "age": "35",
    "location": "Eastern Europe"
   }
}
```

Amazon State Language:

```js
"Flatten": {
  "State": "Pass",
  "Parameters": {
      "name.$" : "$.name",
      "age.$" : "$.lambdaResult.age",
      "location.$": "$.lambdaResult.location"
  },
  "Next": "MyNextState"
}
```

Output:

```js
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": "35",
  "location": "Eastern Europe"
}
```

It's tedious, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend NOT doing the way suggested above as you will drop all data that you do not include. It's not a long term approach, you can more easily do it like this:

**Step Input**

```
{
    "a": "a_value",
    "b": "b_value",
    "c": {
        "c": "c_value"
    }
}
```

**In your state-machine.json**

```
"Flatten And Keep All Other Keys": {
    "Type": "Pass",
    "InputPath": "$.c.c",
    "ResultPath": "$.c",
    "Next": "Some Other State"
}
```

**Step Output**

```
{
    "a": "a_value",
    "b": "b_value",
    "c": "c_value"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would work if there were two attributes you needed to flatten ( like "d": { "d": "d_value" } ), because InputPath can only specify a single item.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your question.

It looks like you don't necessarily need to manipulate the output in any way, and are looking for a way to combine the state's output with its input before passing it on to the next state. The **[ResultPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html)** field allows you to combine a task result with task input, or to select one of these. The path you provide to ResultPath controls what information passes to the output.